# python - remove list like symbol from dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that I created from bunch of .json files, apparently I am getting data in the list form that .json normally formats in.

data:

```
'id'    'col1'
 1a     [student,teacher,missing data]
 22     [teacher]
 de6    []
 34     [missing data, teacher]
 de2    []
 de5    []
```

How do I replace `missing data` from this column?
If it is a string I am able to remove it `missing data`, but not when its in `[ ]` format. Not sure why.

I tried these combination below. I don't get any errors, but it doesn't replace anything.

```
# df['col1'].replace('[]','')
# df['col1'].replace('\[\]','')
# df['col1'].replace('\[','')
# df['col1'].replace('\]','')
df['col1'].replace('missing data','')
```

Output I am looking for it. Is it possible?

```
'id'    'col1'
 1a     [student,teacher]
 22     [teacher]
 de6    []
 34     [teacher]
 de2    []
 de5    []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter out the elements equal to `'missing data'`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['1a', ['student', 'teacher', 'missing data']],
        ['22', ['teacher']],
        ['de6', []],
        ['34', ['missing data', 'teacher']],
        ['de2', []],
        ['de5', []]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['id', 'col1'])

df['col1'] = [[e for e in lst if e != 'missing data'] for lst in df.col1]

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    id                col1
0   1a  [student, teacher]
1   22           [teacher]
2  de6                  []
3   34           [teacher]
4  de2                  []
5  de5                  []
```